# Finding who has the highest number within the array and return the value of the cell

Tags: excel, search, find

|who| vs  |who |scores |
|...|.....|....|.......|
| W |  vs | A  | 3 : 2 |
| C |  vs | B  | 4 : 8 |
| G |  vs | H  | 9 : 7 |

i am trying to do up a scorecard for my Dept and based on this table using EXCEL, the result I wanted will be G given this during this Month, G scores the highest. Please help me out.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the text scores by ":" and the teams by " vs " and formulas image:

[image: formulas image]

```
cell C2 =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2,1)),":",""))

cell D2 =TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(" vs ",A2,1)))

cell E2 =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B2,FIND(":",B2,1)),":",""))
    
cell F2 =TRIM(RIGHT(A2,FIND(" vs ",A2,1)))

cell G2 =IF(MAX(C:C)>MAX(E:E),VLOOKUP(MAX(C:C),C:D,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(MAX(E:E),E:F,2,FALSE))
```